# merge HTML canvas shapes single canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Currently when drawing 2 shapes that overlap that are the same color you can distinguish the 1st shape, as it seems to have a stroke (even when it's set to zero).

```js
var c= document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx =c.getContext('2d')

var b=c.width

ctx.fillStyle="#00f"
ctx.lineWidth=0 //does nothing
ctx.strokeStyle ='#00f' //does nothing

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(b,b)
ctx.lineTo(0,0)
ctx.lineTo(b,b/2)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill()
ctx.moveTo(0,b)
ctx.lineTo(b,0)
ctx.lineTo(0,b/2)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

I'd like them to look like a single shape (they are the same color). Is this possible without 2 canvases?

2 canvases (desired look-don't want multiple canvases):

```js
var c= document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx =c.getContext('2d')
var c2= document.getElementById('canvas2')
var ctx2 =c2.getContext('2d')

var b=c.width

ctx.fillStyle="#00f"
ctx2.fillStyle="#00f"
ctx.lineWidth=0 //does nothing
ctx.strokeStyle ='#00f' //does nothing

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(b,b)
ctx.lineTo(0,0)
ctx.lineTo(b,b/2)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.fill()
ctx2.moveTo(0,b)
ctx2.lineTo(b,0)
ctx2.lineTo(0,b/2)
ctx2.closePath()
ctx2.fill()
```

```css
.wrapper{
position:relative;
}
.wrapper canvas {
position:absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```